# Exporting recursive makefile variables to submakes

Tags: recursion, makefile, export, gnu-make, user-defined-functions

I need to export [a user-defined GNU make function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function) (i.e. [a recursively expanded makefile variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors)) to a sub-make.  However, make seems to expand all such variables into simply expanded variables, which makes them useless.

Here is an example:

Contents of "parent.make":

```
export myfunc = my arg is $1
$(info parent testing myfunc: $(call myfunc,parent))
all: ; $(MAKE) -f child.make
```

Contents of "child.make":

```
$(info child testing myfunc: $(call myfunc,child))
nullrule: ; @true
```

Running "make -f parent.make" produces the following output:

```
parent testing myfunc: my arg is parent
make -f child.make
child testing myfunc: my arg is
```

Parent exports myfunc as a simple expanded variable containing "my arg is" to the sub-make, making it useless as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will satisfy your requirements, but here goes:

parent.make:

```
export myfunc1 = my arg is $1
export myfunc2 = $(value myfunc1)
$(info parent testing myfunc1: $(call myfunc1,parent))
all: ; $(MAKE) -f child.make
```

child.make:

```
$(info child testing myfunc2: $(call myfunc2,child))
nullrule: ; @true
```

**EDIT:**
All right, how about this:

child.make:

```
myfunc1=$(myfunc2)

$(info child testing myfunc1: $(call myfunc1,child))
nullrule: ; @true
```

**EDIT:**

Not so fast. Take a look at this:

parent.make:

```
myfunc_base = my arg is $1

export myfunc = $(value myfunc_base)

$(info parent testing myfunc: $(call myfunc_base,parent))
all: ; @$(MAKE) -f child.make
```

child.make:

```
$(info child testing myfunc: $(call myfunc,child))
nullrule: ;  @$(MAKE) -f grandchild.make
```

grandchild.make:

```
$(info grandchild testing myfunc: $(call myfunc,grandchild))
nullrule: ; @true
```

This works with no modification at all to `child.make` or `grandchild.make`. It does require that `parent.make` call `myfunc_base` rather than `myfunc`; if that's a problem there's a way around it, maybe more than one.

One possibility, we move the definition up into whatever calls `parent`, where it won't actually be called at all:

grandparent.make:

```
myfunc_base = my arg is $1

export myfunc = $(value myfunc_base)

all: ; @$(MAKE) -f child.make
```

parent.make:

```
$(info parent testing myfunc: $(call myfunc,parent))
all: ; @$(MAKE) -f child.make
```

I realize this might not be workable, since the definition of `myfunc` might require other things defined in `parent.make`. See if this will suit your situation; there may be another way...

Comment: That's a neat trick.  However, it doesn't really solve my current problem since I need both parent and child makes to be able to refer to the function using the same name.  (This is in a pre-existing, obsolute, huge, and complex make setup).  My fallback option is to just define these functions in a separate file and include that file for every submake instance, but that is also less than ideal.

Comment: Regarding your edit, this is not really practical.  There are many functions and adding 2 extra lines for each is too verbose.  Also, there are several several levels of makes running sub-makes which further complicates this.  Anyways, I'm going to accept your answer since it seems this is the only available option!

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why common variables and functions can't be put into a separate makefile included by both the parent and the child makefiles?